# how to securely store encrypted password in android using AES and decrypt later?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to save password in android sharedPref using AES algorithm based on my seed and salt. My observation is this algorithm does not generate same encrypted string every time using same salt and seed. I am facing problem while decrypting the encrypted string using same seed. How I can generate same SecretKeySpec with my seed?

Comment: Saving CVV is a violation of PCI standard! You shouldn't do it. You're putting your client's information at risk and inviting trouble to your company

Answer (score 1):

AES is a block cipher and as such requires a block on input data (16-bytes). Either pad the CVV to a block size or specify PKCS#7 padding.

Saving a CVV is probably a violation of the PCI (Payment Card Industry) requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences) library for encrypting data in shared preferences.
But like @zaph wrote it is probably a violation of the PCI.